# How do i connect between user input(Scanner) and if condition in Java

Tags: java, conditional-statements, java.util.scanner

I know i have to use scanner and if condition but i don't know how to connect them

Example:
Are you willing to convert weight or height?
(user input= weight)
Will it be for imperial unit or metric unit?
(user input=metric)
Please provide the weight information in kg
(user input=75)
Your weight in kgs 75.00 is equal to 165.38 in pounds

Comment: Use local variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter an input");
String input= scanner.next();
```

You can start by putting the user input into a variable. Depending on the flow of your program, you might need to parse the input into either integer or float.

```
int integerinput = Integer.parseInt(input);
float floatInput = Float.parseFloat(input);
```

From there, you can start doing the comparison. You have to be careful when parsing information, if the user entered a word and you try to convert that into either integer or float, you will get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You should get user’s input just once:
`String answer = ask.nextLine();`
And then inspect the input with if():
`if (answer.equals("heght")){
             // heght conversion goes here
         }
         else {
             // weght conversion goes here
         }`

Comment: i used this and it gives me an error called cannot find symbol